# iOS Displaying annotations from an array

Tags: ios, xml, arrays, annotations, xml-parsing

I am trying to display multiple annotations on my mapView from an array. The annotation coordinates are parsed from an XML file and stored in the array as [currentCall longitude] and [currentCall latitude]. My question is, what is the syntax for "calling" the array? (I don't know if that's how you say it). In another part of my application, I display the parsed XML results in a table and use "JointCAD *currentCall = [[xmlParser calls] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];" to "call" the array. How do I do it for displaying my annotations? Everything else works fine except that little part.

Here is the implementation file:

```
@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize mapView;

XMLParser *xmlParser;

-(IBAction)getlocation {

mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(IBAction)changeSeg:(id)sender {

if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
}
if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
}
if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
}
}

 -(void)viewDidLoad {

JointCAD *currentCall = [[xmlParser calls] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view insertSubview:mapView atIndex:0];

[super viewDidLoad];
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[mapView setDelegate:self];

MKCoordinateRegion WCCCA = { {0.0, 0.0} , {0.0, 0.0} };
WCCCA.center.latitude = 45.53540820864449;
WCCCA.center.longitude = -122.86178648471832;
WCCCA.span.longitudeDelta = 0.02f;
WCCCA.span.latitudeDelta = 0.02f;
[mapView setRegion:WCCCA animated:YES];

Annotation *ann1 = [[Annotation alloc] init];
ann1.title = @"WCCCA";
ann1.subtitle = @"Washington County Consolidated Communications Agency";
ann1.coordinate = WCCCA.center;
[mapView addAnnotation: ann1];

MKCoordinateRegion CALL = { {0.0, 0.0} , {0.0, 0.0} };
CALL.center.latitude = [currentCall.latitude doubleValue];
CALL.center.longitude = [currentCall.longitude doubleValue];
CALL.span.longitudeDelta = 0.02f;
CALL.span.latitudeDelta = 0.02f;
[mapView setRegion:WCCCA animated:YES];

Annotation *ann2 = [[Annotation alloc] init];
ann2.title = [currentCall currentCallType];
ann2.subtitle = [currentCall location];
ann2.coordinate = CALL.center;
[mapView addAnnotation: ann1];

}

-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"current"];
MyPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

UIButton *advertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[advertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(button:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

MyPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = advertButton;
MyPin.draggable = NO;
MyPin.highlighted = YES;
MyPin.animatesDrop=TRUE;
MyPin.canShowCallout = YES;

return MyPin;
}

 @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your code properly, you should be able to just iterate through your parsed XML (it appears that the output the from your xmlParser object is an NSArray) and add the annotations to the mapView within the loop.

You can use the C function `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake()` to create the coordinate data structure for your annotation.

```
NSArray *callsArray = [xmlParser calls];

for (JointCAD *call in callsArray) {
    Annotation *ann = [[Annotation alloc] init];
    ann.title = [call currentCallType];
    ann.subtitle = [call location];
    ann.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([call latitude], [call longitude]);
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
}
```

Comment: When I try that, I get a Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CLLocationCoordinate2DMake", referenced from:
      -[SecondViewController viewDidLoad] in SecondViewController.o

Comment: Nevermind, Im retarded. I forgot to add the framework to the project.